# Интересно, а кто это начал...  Куська бятая, мутявлики козятые, По - моему, великолепно!

Tags: этимология

И что восхищает,  ласковость и все понимание!!!!! Как ты там не прухасинкай или не  выпасусивайся. Эзопова мова? Но тышко накроме туху нетротрой люху.--- ты не прав.

Answer (score 2):

Что именно начал? Про "глокую куздру " - Щерба. ПроКуську бятую - Людмила Петрушевская.

http://rus.1september.ru/2005/14/6.htm - интересное исследование ученицы на эту тему

Answer (score 1):

Макаронический язык существует едва столько же, сколько и язык вообще.
И у Щербы, и у Петрушевской, и еще в ряде известных "произведений" - не совсем макаронизмы, просто слова надуманные/изобретенные, но суть та же. 
Отчасти подпадает под определение "глоссолалия".

Про язык Петрушевской.

*Сказки состоят целиком из несуществующих слов (кроме служебных). Петрушевская использует как традиционные для таких произведений системы словообразования из случайных слогов, называемые глоссолалия, так и более оригинальные и интересные, например, современные или устаревшие корни (а также несуществующие сочетания корневых основ русского языка, несуществующие замены корневых гласных или согласных), которые употребляются писательницей в рассказах с такими русскими аффиксами, с которыми в настоящем русском языке они обычно или не употребляются, или употребляться не могут ввиду полной бессмысленности образованных подобным образом слов.*

*Иногда в рассказах употребляются старославянские предлоги или междометия.*

*Из произвольно взятых корневых основ других современных языков индоевропейской или даже кавказской языковой семьи употребляются некоторые русские языковые аффиксы (суффиксы, приставки, окончания, соединительные гласные), подобранные к ним самой писательницей особым образом и поэтому не являющиеся традиционными лингвистическими заимствованиями, характерными для реального языка.*

*Тем не менее, подобные причудливые формы словообразования у писательницы созданы так, что составляют некий связный рассказ с интуитивно понятным сюжетом. Впоследствии цикл «Лингвистические сказочки» был автором продолжен с включением новых удивительных, а подчас и совершенно фантастических персонажей и соответствующим развитием как сюжетов, так и самих героев.*

*Слово некузявый (в значении «плохой», «неподходящий») и производные от него благодаря сказке иногда встречается в разговорном русском языке, а слово бутявка (от англ. boot) в компьютерном сленге обозначает "загрузка".*

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5